# Can't get flexbox container to expand horizontally to match content

Tags: flexbox

The flex layout below is working *except* the content container (blue) is sized by the columnar items *before* they wrap.

I want the blue container to expand to the right to fit the content (ie the horizontal measure *after* the items wrap)

Any hints would be appreciated.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Some more research shows that this is a well-known, long standing, bug, but only for the column orientation, not for the row orientation.

So the solution is to switch to "upside down" day. Turn the column into a row with the css `writing-mode:'vertical-lr'`, then specify `flex-direction:'row` to match, and it works!

... but all direct children need to have their writing mode reset: `writing-mode:horizontal-tb`